# angular/fire installation script returns Invalid project id

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to create an authentication page for firebase login. Following the documentation for the @angular/fire package, I created an angular project with `ng new angular_fbauth`. Then I ran `ng add @angular/fire` I got through the installation prompt up to choosing my login. I chose my login, and the script immediately returns `Invalid project id: angular_fbauth`. Now, what I don't understand is why is the script looking for a firebase project with a name identical to my angular project? Is this how angular/fire is supposed to work? I find it strange that the front end application would need to match identically with the firebase project considering that multiple "apps" can be connected to one "project".

I did try `firebase use` and chose the project explicitly, however the script still returns the same error message.

EDIT:

I changed the project name in my angular.json to match the firebase project, and I now instead get prompted to choose a project. This doesn't seem like it is the intended behavior.

```
"projects": {
    "jldemo-7698d": {
```

[Choose a project prompt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCzlr.png)